# Having issues when using a JOIN query against a UNION query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 mysql tables. user,profile and event. user and profile have one to one relation. (One user can have one profile).

But single profile can have multiple events. So its one to many between profile and events. I need to have a query with a LEFT JOIN to retrieve the row details in profile and events. But still I need the name column which is in the user table to be included in the output result. So it should be a UNION query between user and profile based on the userId table and the complete one should be a join with the event table[image]

Would be great if anyone can help with the query

See the following query. Instead of using only the profile in this below query I need an union of the user and profile to be added to the circled area. A little help would be appreciated[image]

Comment: Please see [mcve]. The table details seem off since you have used `professionalID` vs `professionID` in places. What is the correct column name? What is the expected output? Some sample data along with other things will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: are u using left join because you want all profiles or all events?